# Swipe actions for row with iOS system icons instead of text

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swipe

I've set up a destructive trailing swipe action under iOS 11:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, view, completionHandler) in
      self.deleteRow(atIndexPath: indexPath)
      completionHandler(true)
    })

    // Is it possible here?
    //deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")

    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    return configuration
  }
```

Instead of the "delete" text, I'd like to show the Apple system icon thrash bin found here:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/system-icons/

Obviously, I could obtain the icon from somewhere and set it as the image, but I guess there should be a native way to do this.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: You cannot set image for native swipe action except some work arounds like background , I suggest to use the awesome  SwipeCellKit library  https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit

Comment: @Hosny Setting an image is now possible in iOS 11 (as shown here at 28:45 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/). My issue is, I want the system icon image for "thrash"/"delete"

Comment: Ok, thanks for this tip

Comment: Download the SF Symbols application, in it you can find the system icon names, then you can instantiate your image with eg.: UIImage(systemName: "trash.circle", compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)